# compare 2 columns from 2 different tables and update a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare a column in table a and table b

If the a value from table a can be found in table b then I want to update another column in table a with a 'yes' and if it cannot be found I want to say 'no'. This is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE a 
set
[CCA Match Org] = CASE WHEN b.[serial] = a.[CSI] THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
```

My error at the moment says:

> The column prefix 'b' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: How are tables a and b related?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the join is on `b.[serial] = a.[CSI]`:

```
UPDATE a
SET [CCA Match Org] = CASE WHEN b.[serial] IS NOT NULL 
  THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON b.[serial] = a.[CSI];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick example, not sure if it will work in your case because you didnt give us more info on the table structures.

```
UPDATE a SET col='Yes' WHERE a.id IN (SELECT a.id FROM a JOIN b ON a.CSI = b.serial)
```